# Deducing that an analytic function $f$ in a simply connected domain $\Omega$ is the derivative of an analytic function $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected domain, i.e. open and connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ be analytic in $\Omega$. I am trying to understand how you can deduce that $f(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F(z)$ for some analytic function $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ from the two following results (which are verbatim from my old notes handed in class):

1.) **Monodromy theorem**: If $\Omega$ is simply connected and $f:\Omega'\to\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function which admits an analytic continuation along any path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ with the starting point of $\gamma$ staying in $\Omega'$, then $f$ has a direct analytic continuation to $\Omega$.

2.) If $f$ is an analytic function in a domain $\Omega$ and $F$ is its primitive, i.e. $\frac{d}{dz}F(z) = f(z)$, then $F$ has an analytic continuation along $F_k:\Omega_k\to\mathbb{C}, k=1,\dots,n$, i.e. $F_{k+1}\equiv F_k$ in $\Omega_{k+1}\cap \Omega_k$, where $\Omega_k$s are **discs** and $\frac{d}{dz}F_k(z) = f(z)$ in $\Omega_k$.

(**Thoughts:**) My current understanding is nil in the sense that I do not see what Monodromy theorem has to do with the second result, which likely used to conclude the result. Specifically, the analytic continuation along $F_k$ of the second result almost fit with out need: Their derivative agrees with $f$ on the disks $\Omega_k$. To satisfy our case we would need to inflate some of (or all) the disks $\Omega_k$ so that inflated $\tilde{\Omega_k} = \Omega$. But I just don't see how this happens with the Monodromy theorem.

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, the function $F(w) = \int_{\gamma_{w_0, w}}f(z)dz$ will do as such an analytic function where $w_0\in\Omega$ is fixed and $\gamma_{w_0, w}$ is a path contained in $\Omega$ connecting $w_0$ and $w$. But what is still unclear to me is that where do we need the two stated theorems? To me the only thing we need is to be able to conclude that in simply connected domains, the path integral of an analytic function depends only on the initial and terminal point.

Comment: Do you know about integration along paths?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I do, but not enough that "integration along paths" alone would connect the pieces together for me.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$ depends only on the endpoints of $\gamma$ and not on the path itself (in the case of simply connected domains)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This I do know, as per the simply connectedness and analyticity of $f$. This is just a thought, but could we maybe fix $w_0\in\Omega$ and define $F(w)\equiv \int_{\gamma_{w_0,w}}f(z)dz$ where $\gamma_{w_0, w}$ is a path in $\Omega$ connecting $w_0$ and $w$? This way $F'(w)=f(w)$ for $w\neq w_0$. But then again, we would have to add something extra to $F$ for otherwise $F'(w_0)=0$ while $f$ might not vanish at $w_0$.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. You are mistaken about the derivative at $w_0$, it will be $f(w_0)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are correct. Okay, knowing that our prior $F$ will do, can you comment on deducing this result with the results 1.) and 2.) I had listed? IMO we are only using the fact that the path integral of an analytic function in simply connected domains depends only on the initial and terminal point.

Comment: Part (2) makes no sense at all. Part 1, I think, is a garbled version of the usual monodromy principle: As stated, it is useless (too garbled). If I were to prove the result using the monodromy principle (that you can find in any textbook, I would first argue that primitive exists in disks (for instance, treating the problem as a PDE question). Then argue that the solution of the result is analytic in the disk. Then connect two given points in $\Omega$ by a polygonal path $\gamma$, cover the latter by disks and apply the preceding argument to construct an analytic continuation $F$...

Comment: along $\gamma$, so that $F'=f$ on the union of disks. Then use the monodromy principle to show that $F$ is a well-defined holomorphic function on $\Omega$, i.e. is independent of the paths $\gamma$. Needless to say, this is a much harder proof that using Cauchy's theorem.